# Did Ava pass the Turing test?

Tags: ex-machina

Very simple question, in Ex Machina did Ava pass the Turing test? Or was it just that she

> was smarter than Caleb and tricked him into helping her escape?

Comment: I can not give a better answer than @valorum did but I think there is a second test being given, either explicitly or implicitly. If an object display's sentience then does said object have right? The 2nd seasons of Humans seems to be highlighting that question.

Comment: How does she feel about you asking this question? ;-)

Comment: It was one and the same for her creator, so why it isn't for you?

Comment: @Mithoron, I don't follow, what are you trying to say?

Comment: _sigh_ You have two options in body of your text, in the movie second (spoilered) one meant the first for her creator - if she had done it, she passed. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Mithoron, you are making the assumption that is what it meant to Nathan, b/c the way I remember he does not actually say that she did (pass) and further more that he stated that seducing Calub  could have been a ploy and not in fact true AI. Back up your assumptions with some facts please.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This was discussed in an interview with the film's writer/director Alex Garland. In short, Ava could pass a *classic* Turing test (blind, with the interrogator in another room) without breaking a sweat. What Nathan is interested in is not whether she can pass an arbitrary test of language and response but whether she's actually sentient and conscious.

> **Q. So Domhnall’s character is administering a Turing Test…**
>
> **Garland:** *Sort of. It’s pedantic, but it’s sort of a post-Turing Test. It’s a blind test. A Turing Test is really a test to see if you can pass the
> Turing Test. You can pass the Turing Test and not be sentient. What
> he’s saying is, **this machine would pass the traditional form of the
> Turing Test; I want to know if I can show you it’s a machine, and you
> still think it’s sentient.** It’s a step up.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Alex Garland On ‘Ex Machina’, Oscar Isaac, the Fate of the ‘Dredd’ Sequel](http://waytooindie.com/interview/interview-alex-garland-ex-machina-414/)</sup></sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that Alan Turing devised the test precisely as a means of operationally settling the question of machine intelligence *without* allowing humans preconceived notions of a machine being unable to think because of *insert reason here* (like, pertinently, not having a body). So the writer's assertion that "you can pass the Turing Test and not be sentient" is essentially him either saying "the Turing test doesn't really work" or "you can be intelligent without being sentient". Both interesting takes, even if they miss the point of the original test somewhat.

Comment: *"without allowing humans preconceived notions of a machine being unable to think"* ...by making humans the ultimate judge of the machine's intelligence?  I think the Turing test is an interesting thought experiment but is waaaay overrated; I think it fails to do exactly that which you say it tries to do; be objective. It is strongly biased towards human language/experience. Talking to a computer about the taste of strawberries (or any other thing it could never experience), then judging it's intelligence based on that conversation seems pretty stupid to me...

Comment: @JeroenMostert - As we learn more about language acquisition, we find that it's moderately easy to pass a Turing test. Many people talk to their Siri, for example and are surprised to find that it talks back, seemingly intelligently.

Comment: @StijndeWitt: as much as I'd love to discuss the merits of the Turing test exhaustively (and I really would, it's a topic dear to my heart) these comments would be too small to contain such a discussion. I'm merely pointing out what Turing's original intent was and what the writer's comments mean in that light.

Comment: @Valorum: that's the ELIZA effect. The Turing test isn't about whether a program can fool a layman in casual conversation, but whether someone who *knows* they might be talking to bot can conclusively determine if it's a bot or not. Most bots fold almost immediately under scrutiny when forced to demonstrate an ability to think (not merely talk), even if they have a few tricks up their sleeve to obfuscate and misdirect. The classical form of the Turing test had two contestants (one human, and one machine) for the judge to distinguish, which raises the stakes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert All of that is true. However, it is also true that more recent advances in technology have shown that the Turing Test isn't as important as it once was believed to be. It will probably be beaten well before we have anything that can be considered to be true intelligence. It's still interesting, just not as pivotal.

Comment: @Jasper: Alan Turing's contention was that if a program is capable of convincing dedicated interrogators with no restriction on discourse that it thinks, then it is permissible to say (as we do for anonymous humans online!) that it *does* think, for all *practical* purposes, regardless of what anyone considers "true" intelligence (which has so far turned out to be continuous shifting of goal posts). One is of course free to disagree with that definition, or contend that "sentience" is a much broader concept, but advances in natural language processing aren't immediately salient to that.

Comment: Also note that even if one ignores the shortcomings that the Turing Test has, it's important to distinguish between its use as a detector vs. a discriminator.  That is, one use is "X is intelligent if and only if it passes a Turing Test".  Another use is "if X passes a Turing Test, then it is intelligent", which doesn't preclude the possibility of an intelligent agent that, despite its intelligence, can't pass a Turing Test.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of a Turing Test states:

> "a test for intelligence in a computer, requiring that a human being should be unable to distinguish the machine from another human being by using the replies to questions put to both."

The interrogator in this case was made aware of it being a machine, and aesthetically she is clearly a robot. In the letter of the definition it was not a Turing Test, though in the spirit of it as a "test of humanism and intelligence" Ava displayed distinctly human traits (manipulation, deceit, rage).

Comment: Why is this in spoiler tags? I hope you don't mind my edits to your answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure if i should spoiler or not - if you hadn't seen the film, you wouldn't know that the premise of the film was that the interrogator was already aware of ava's origin :)

Also, i appreciate the edits as they make the answer i'm giving much clearer - thanks :)

Comment: I didn't get that from your answer, although I haven't had any interest in the films. But Spoilers are usually reserved for if the OP says they've only read X far through a series, and so you leave answers from future parts in spoilers so those that have read further can see the answers, or for very new works like Logan, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your advice on this, I'm still very new to stackexchange - i actually answered a logan question recently and used spoiler tags there ( hopefully correctly that time! ) so that is useful to know.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I've been hiding from logan as I've not seen it yet haha, will get round to upvoting answers there soon enough :) Stick around and earn some of the [easier badges](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=bronze) while you start.